# Pass a message to parent inside UIGestureRecognizer handler?

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, drag-and-drop, uigesturerecognizer

Forgive me if this has been asked elsewhere; I searched thoroughly and couldn't find anything.  I am (brand) new to iOS development, and I'm learning things the Objective-C way.  I've run across an issue where I am trying to drag-and-drop an image across a ViewController, and have one of the ViewController's methods be invoked upon 1) beginning and 2) ending the drag-and-drop.  My sub-UIImageView class has its own `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, and the drag-and-drop works flawlessly given the code below (this is within "DrawableImageView.h", my subview class, added properly to the ViewController with `[self.view addSubView:subview]`):

```
- (id)initWithObject:(Drawable*)obj parent:(ViewController*)viewcontroller
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        self.object = obj;
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:pan];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        [_parent eventAtLocationX:self.center.x Y:self.center.y];
        //NSLog(@"began");
    }
    [self.superview bringSubviewToFront:self];
    CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self.superview];
    self.center = CGPointMake( self.center.x + translation.x, self.center.y + translation.y );
    [sender setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.superview];

    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        [_parent eventAtLocationX:self.center.x Y:self.center.y];
        //NSLog(@"ended");
    }
}
```

As I said, the drag and drop works perfectly, and the `NSLog()`s (commented out in the above code) are executed at the proper times, upon beginning and ending the drag and drop, respectively.  However, the message send to the parent class is not.  It is not done at all, it seems; when I breakpoint and try to step into the message send, it briefly jumps back to the iOS simulator, and then just skips to the `NSLog()`.  I've also tried to put the breakpoint within the `eventAtLocationX: Y:` method itself, and it is not triggered, confirming that the method is never invoked at all.

I am sure this has to do with some misunderstanding on my part about the nature of UIGestureRecognizer selectors, the way that these are handled by iOS, the nature of spacetime, or the foundations of the universe itself.  I hope you can elucidate me, as it is getting late over here on a school/work night.

and forgive the n00bness.  Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: And, where exactly you are assigning the value to the `parent` property? I suspect, you are not assigning anything to that property, that's why your method is not being triggered.

Comment: Ugh.  Thank you, works perfectly now that I've added that to the constructor.  I told you it was getting late.  I would have expected maybe a runtime error for doing what I did, what gives?  Are Objective-C private instance variables default-initialized, or what?

Comment: By the way, yes, `_parent` is an instance variable declared under the `@interface` declaration in curly braces, not a property.

Comment: No, they are not initialized by default. They are just `nil` before the initialization. Before, i don't exactly remember, it would throw exception for this kind of errors, but now it's not, so while debugging you can check the variable, if it is initialized or it's nil.

Comment: Fair enough.  I appreciate your help; I'm annoyed and relieved it was such a little mistake!